# Jquery Notification Popups - jquery and updatepanels

Tags: c#, jquery

Hi i want notifications to popup if the need arises. I am using an asp.net timer which checks if a new message has arrived. The problem i am getting is that the jquery notification does not show up. I am guessing this is something to do with the update panel. Because when i tried calling it from pageload it worked fine. Here is my code;

```
    protected void updateTimer_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cache Cache = new Cache();

        users = Cache.getUserDetailsByUserID(Convert.ToInt32(Page.User.Identity.Name));

        if (users._bNewNotification)
        {
            List<UserNotification> listUserNotification = null;

            listUserNotification = Cache.getLatestNotifcationsByUserID(Convert.ToInt32(Page.User.Identity.Name));

            foreach (UserNotification userNotification in listUserNotification)
            {
                StringBuilder jquery2 = new StringBuilder();

                jquery2.AppendLine("$.extend($.gritter.options, {");
                jquery2.AppendLine("position: 'bottom-left',");
                jquery2.AppendLine("fade_in_speed: 100,");
                jquery2.AppendLine("fade_out_speed: 100,");
                jquery2.AppendLine("time: 3000");
                jquery2.AppendLine("});");
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), jquery2.ToString(), true);

                StringBuilder jquery1 = new StringBuilder();
                jquery1.AppendLine("   var unique_id = $.gritter.add({");
                jquery1.AppendLine("        title: 'This is a sticky notice!',");
                jquery1.AppendLine("        text: '" + userNotification._NotificationType + "',");
                jquery1.AppendLine("        image: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/132499022/myface_bigger.jpg',");
                jquery1.AppendLine("        sticky: true,");
                jquery1.AppendLine("        time: '',");
                jquery1.AppendLine("        class_name: 'my-sticky-class'");
                jquery1.AppendLine("    });");
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), jquery1.ToString(), true);
            }

            users._bNewNotification = false;
            users.UpdateNewNotification();

            Cache.RemoveUserProfileCacheByUserID(users._USERS_ID);
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out what it is i am doing wrong, thanks

Comment: Have you looked in a Javascript debugger / browser console to check for runtime errors?

Comment: Yes there are no errors being thrown. Will i need to reload my javascript files again because i know the function relies on the files being loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach won't work. When the browser gets your page it disconnects, so your **server-side** C# timer event handler code will have no browser to talk to.

You need to do something like implement polling on the web page in **client-side** JavaScript. e.g.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $.get('path/to/GetNotifications.aspx', function(data){
            // data contains text from GetNotifications.aspx
            // it could be JSON, XML, CSV... it's up to you
            // do something with it here...
        })
    },5000 /*5s*/)
})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding, i am trying to return the jquery which is in my stringbuilder above how do i go about doing that, sorry if it sounds like a silly question.

Comment: Like I said: Your approach won't work. You need to just embed the client-side polling code in the ASPX page, and write a sort of "service" page that retrieves the notifications for you.